# Joomla 3 permissions setup

Tags: joomla-3.x, permissions

I am using Joomla 3.4.3 and I am trying to give permissions to a specific group. I want this group to `Create/Edit/Delete` articles in a specific category.

I have created a group under `Registered` users. Then in `System -> Global Configuration -> Permissions` I am giving the permission of `Admin Login`, `Access Administration Interface`, etc. When I login as a user from this group in the upper menu I can only see the `SP Page Builder` option.

How can I enable the `Content` menu in order to have access (`Create/Edit/Delete`) to the `Categories` and `Articles`? 
I don't want to give `Manager` permissions, because I want to give the less the permission I can.

Comment: Please update to 3.4.8 before anything. You're current version is prone to attackers. Recent updates fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

From the backend go to Global Configuration
Click Articles in the left hand sidebar
Go to the permissions tab and edit the permissions for the group you created
Save

If you want to deny access to all of the other components (banners, weblinks, etc) go to those components and kill the access for the group you created.